# Defining a PHP class constant within a function

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to define a constant within a class function?
Example:

```
class ExampleApp
{
    const FORM = TRUE;

    public function __construct()
    {
        switch(Base::color())
        {
            case 'green':
                self::FORM = 'G';
                break;
            case 'red':
                self::FORM = 'R';
                break;
            default:
                self::FORM = 'W';
                break;
        }
    }

    public function process() { return TRUE; }
}
```

The above example code won't work obviously!

From my programming knowledge you can't redefine constants else they would be "constants". But how do you define a costant within a function?! In my example that function being the constructor, or is this entirely not possible?

Comment: You could use `define` to declare a constant at run-time instead of parse-time. I would simply use a variable and promise not to modify it.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over `constant` versus `static`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By saving it in a property. NOT a static property, just a property with getters and setters.

```
class ExampleApp
{
    const FORM_COLOR_GREEN = "G";
    const FORM_COLOR_RED = "R";
    const FORM_COLOR_DEFAULT = "W";

    private $form_color;

    public function getFormColor()
    {
        return $this->form_color;

    }

    public function setFormColor( $color )
    {
        $this->form_color = $color;

    }

    public function __construct( $color = NULL )
    {
        switch( $color )
        {
            case 'green':
                $this->setFormColor( self::FORM_COLOR_GREEN );
                break;
            case 'red':
                $this->setFormColor( self::FORM_COLOR_RED );
                break;
            default:
                $this->setFormColor( self::FORM_COLOR_DEFAULT );
                break;
        }
    }

    public function process() { return TRUE; }
}
```

Then you can get the form colour by calling it with `$example_app->getFormColor();`

Answer (score 8):

I think you wanted a static property, not a constant

`public static $form = true;`

However, don't put variable name in uppercase letters then, since it's not a constant, not to confuse other developers.

You can asccess it like you did in your methods with `self::form`

Comment: -> Reply: I suppose the solution would be to use a "static" variable (not truly a constant but behaves as one) within the function or just a normal constant using define().

Comment: It really depends what you want to do, but either way, I think you need what @Hayden suggested in his answer, or my answer with a static property

Comment: When accessing a `static` property you must include the dollar sign. The correct way to access the `$form` property would be `self::$form`.